# jni_zero : Compilation error of M120 webrtc android

Tags: android, compilation, webrtc, voip

I have used following commands for webrtc android compilation on Ubuntu 22.04
Python version : 3.8
OpenJDK version : 11

1. git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
2. cd depot_tools
3. export PATH=/usr/local/webrtc_android/depot_tools:$PATH
4. fetch --nohooks webrtc_android
5. gclient sync
6. setup proxy on separate location for reaching ubuntu servers

vi /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy

Acquire::http::Proxy "PROXYSERVER.com:PORT";

7. run ./build/install-build-deps.sh
8. cd src
9. git branch -r

   git checkout  branch-heads/6099
10. tools_webrtc/android/build_aar.py

On compilation of build_aar.py, getting the following error saying "undefined identifier jni_zero"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfKr4.png)

Can any one help on how to get the jni_zero issue fixed ...

Thanks in advance,
Nagaraju Samudrala

I was expecting a successful compilation of the command - "tools_webrtc/android/build_aar.py" and android aar file getting generated.